# Heroku css background image doesn't work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm very frustrated as I have a rails application and locally everything works fine.
I use some css background images but after deploying on Heroku the css background images were not shown...

I have googled a lot and I know thats a problem with static assets but no solution works for me.

in my **css.erb file**:

```
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
background-image: image-url("ich.jpg");
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
background-image: image-url("gruen.jpg");
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
 background-image: image-url("see.jpg");
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-4 {
 background-image: image-url("huette.jpg");
}
```

I' have added this to my **gemfile**:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

And I have added following to my **config/production.rb**:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

But nothing works :(. When I deploy the project to heroku a get no background images and following **log message**:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches GET]"/images/huette.jpg"):
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches GET]"/images/see.jpg"):
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches GET]"/images/gruen.jpg"):
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches GET]"/images/ich.jpg"):
```

Comment: did you try running:  heroku run rake assets:precompile?

Comment: Yes I have done: " rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production" before deploying the project. :(

Comment: please try: heroku run rake assets:precompile

Comment: Ok I tried: "heroku run rake assets:precompile" after deploying...unfortunately it dosnt work :(    It is necessary to restart the server or something else?

Comment: I got:  Running rake assets:precompile on ypurApp... up, run.6327
I, [2016-07-29T12:06:55.645491 #3]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-fa5771c0b7a9267
ad3a01a06468c350c.js
I, [2016-07-29T12:06:57.518505 #3]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/app_design-aeffb3c4c2c299ab
a9c9136809ddef21.css
I, [2016-07-29T12:07:27.799927 #3]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-9e6a11106b17172
b5dd0de3ce58b3937.css
I, [2016-07-29T12:07:27.928166 #3]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/style-f193a906435cbf40464ab
99c34ed5516.css

Comment: yes you can try heroku restart, I think It should have to pick the images after pricompilation.

Comment: Restart was not the solution. When I see it correctly above in the output after the precompile he just precompile .css and .js but no images?

Comment: Thanks for your help too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to call your images when they are in the asset folder:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

Try that and let us know.